# IPTC and custom thumb size

Tags: media

I've created some additional custom thumb sizes for images. Original image has EXIF and IPTC datas which are important for me. But images generated for new thumbs has not these datas. They are important for me to keep copyrights informations on each image on site. Is this possible to get these parameters on each image?

Thanks!

Comment: Please deactivate all the plugins and having only the code for your new image size, please try again, and let us know whether issue is there or not.

Comment: Ok. I dig and I found, that in WP 5.3 is new feature - image downscaling. I see there is option to disable scaling by 'add_filter( 'big_image_size_threshold', '__return_false' );' but it's not working, even for new images!

Comment: UPDATE: works only for new images... ridiculous!!

Comment: What about using [Regenerate Thumbnails](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) plugin?

Comment: Not in this case :/